# Track moving object in Python

Tags: python, image

I have a set of subsequent images (2000), where an object oscillate up and down continuously (a squared marker placed on a cyclist knee). I would like to track that object and have the center coordinates of the object for each image (the object doesn't change shape but just location).
How should I do it?

Thanks

I think I should use cv2 or tensorflow, but looking the documentation I didn't find anything interesting for my case

Comment: I think a bit more information is needed. Is this an object taken in real world and hard to separate? Can you use template matching if it is an object from e.g. a screen recording? Once you have a way to detect the object, getting its center and oscillation throughout the sequence should be straight forward.

Comment: Right now I'm giving to python manually the coordinates of a square all around this particular object and then using a normxcorr2 to find it in the subsequent images.
Basically is marker placed on the cyclist knee that I have to track (the position) in subsequent recorded images

Comment: Is there a detector that is able to find the marker reliably like for apriltags, checkerboards, qr-codes of any sort or anything? Is it possible to provide an example?

Comment: Exactly this one https://github.com/Sabrewarrior/normxcorr2-python